# Android: Button always shown

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

I wanted to make a button always set at the bottom of the page but will move so it is always shown. The main reason I want this is because when you click into an edit text field the keyboard will pop-up and hide the button. I would like the button to move so it sits above the keyboard when in a field and then will return to the bottom when the keyboard is hidden. Currently I am using a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFF0">

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/titlebar1" android:background="#082386"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titlebar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/NewUsedSpinner" android:prompt="@string/NewUsed_prompt"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NewUsedSpinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MakeSpinner" android:prompt="@string/Make_prompt">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MakeSpinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ModelSpinner" android:prompt="@string/Model_prompt"></Spinner>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NewUsedSpinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TrimSpinner" android:prompt="@string/Trim_prompt"></Spinner>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/PriceSpinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TrimSpinner" android:prompt="@string/Price_prompt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"></Spinner>



    <TextView android:text="Search within the radius of:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PriceSpinner" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/FilterZip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"></TextView>



    <Spinner android:id="@+id/ZipSpinner" android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/Zip_prompt"></Spinner>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ZipSpinner"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Zip" android:id="@+id/FilterZip"
        android:maxLength="5" android:numeric="integer"></EditText>


    <Button android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/FilterSearchbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Search" android:layout_below="@+id/ZipSpinner"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn" android:textStyle="bold"></Button>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Android manifest you would add this to your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Here's the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Maybe try `alignParentBottom="true"` on the button so that it will always be on the bottom, you'll have to fiddle with your layout.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but it only works well for the edittext field, which is nice but not exactly what i'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to get my button to stay above the softinput so once the keyboard comes up the button will be pushed from the bottom to above the keyboard.

Comment: This is definitely what you're looking for, I think you just have to make the button alignment properly. Edited my answer.

Comment: okay, I'll mess around. I already have alignparentbottom on my button but I agree that you're probably right.

Comment: Oh - you cant have android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" AND android:layout_below="@+id/ZipSpinner" these two will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If we want to only adjust the screen without view which has (alignParentBottom="true") in relative layout then set below line in activity tag in manifest.xml

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

(2) If we want to adjust the whole relative layout with the view which has (alignParentBottom="true") in relative layout then set  below line in activity tag in manifest.xml

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

(3) If we don't want to adjust the whole relative layout without the view which has (alignParentBottom="true") in relative layout then set  below line in activity tag in manifest.xml

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

(4) If we remove line android:windowSoftInputMode from the manifest.xml then it will behave like (2) option